# What's the difference between fluorescent and LED "grow lamps"?

Tags: indoors, light

I've been studying a bit on how to take care of my Ming Aralia inside my office, and some sources mainly mention fluorescent lamps and how they should be placed very near to the leaves, almost touching. I didn't find similar instructions on grow lights (the red+blue lamps).

What's the difference between them and how they should be handled? Inside the fluorescent group, is there a difference between cold and warm lamps? What about lamp distance from the plant?

Answer (score 2):

Fluorescents come in a wide variety of light spectrum outputs You can find information more readily under Aquarium Lighting. Reportedly some colors like "cool white" do not have necessary spectrum for chlorophyll.LED operate on a different principle but with a similar result; very limited spectrum that depends on the particular LED.  Also both have ranges of light intensity in their particular spectrum ranges. Generally they should be close to the plant to provide enough light intensity. Probably easiest to use the manufactures recommendations unless you want to make a project out of it. I have used many of both ( and metal halide) but have no particular insight , I tend to use LEDs ( with white/blue/red) because they are convenient and I do get some daylight on my aquariums.